# Bijection between powerset and increasing-ordered tuples

Tags: combinatorics, functions, combinatorial-proofs

I'm trying to write a formal proof that there exists a bijection between two sets,

Namely, If I take $E$ a set of integers and $(x_i)_{i\in\{1,\dots,n\}}$ a sequence of elements of $E$ sorted in *strictly* (that is no duplicates) increasing order, then the mapping defined by :

$$\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}\mapsto (x_1,\dots,x_n)$$ where the result is the ordered $n$-tuple, should be a bijection.

I wrote down what sorted in increasing order means :

$$\forall i \in \{1,\dots,n-1\},\quad x_i<x_{i+1}$$

It follows clearly that $E$ must contain (shifting if necessary) $\{1,\dots,n\}$ for this to work, so we can assume $E=\{1,\dots,m\}$ with $m\geq n$

But I don't know how to go on with the proof.

Any help will be appreciated

thanks!

Comment: Induction on $n$? Can you prove the base case $n=1$, and perhaps $n=2$ for practice, before going to the induction step? Isolating the largest element (both in the set and in the ordered list) might help in formulating the induction.

Comment: how do you isolate it, formally ?

Comment: The largest element of the ordered tuple is $x_n$?

Comment: @JukkaKohonen Yes.

Comment: So you have isolated it.